# Netbeans + Facelets + Jboss EL

Tags: jsf, netbeans, java-ee-5

I've got a problem with JBossEL in NetBeans. Jboss EL provides method execution besides java bean binding. So th code :

```
<h:outputText value="#{welcomeController.getWelcome(request)}" />
```

is correct and works fine. But NetBeans shows me an error:

> The function getWelcome must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

How to make NetBeans compatilble with JbossEL ?
I'm using Facelets if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore and run.

If those errors annoy you, just disable/reconfigure the JSP EL validator somewhere in the IDE settings.